# how to add new row in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add a new row in table on button click, its adding row but no binding dropdown

i have tried this

```
 $("#btnAddRow").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var value = $("#TnoOfRows").val();
            for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
                $('#example').clone().appendTo('<tr><td><select class="form-control ddlClient" /></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control dtpicker" /> </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" /></td><td><button class="btn bg-teal-400 addInvoice" title="Add Your Invoices" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="icon-plus2"></i></button>&nbsp<input type="button" class="form-control"  value="Delete" /></td></tr>')

            }
        });
        $('#example').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
```

Comment: You don't have any options binding into select, my friend!  "<select class="form-control ddlClient" />"

Comment: <select class="form-control ddlClient"><option value"">Select</option></select> No option tag in select